# Why does the Script Editor not work for a survey

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Since MS SharePoint 2013 has a save and close button for surveys then of course all my responders click on save and close before the survey is over !  I want to hide the save and close button.  Of course we can not use SP designer were I am at so I tried using the below js in a Script Editor for the new. aspx and edit .aspx pages of the survey but it does not work.

I have used the Script Editor Webpart in other pages in my site without issue..  Any ideas...Isn't the purpose of the Script Editor Webpart to be able to run javascript...  Note I have not loaded any javascript run files anywhere in my site..The only js I am running is below..

Was curious how the js file can run within the Script Windo without me providing a URL for the js library ?

Here is the [link](http://danssharepointblog.blogspot.com/2014/01/how-to-hide-save-close-for-surveys.html), but note I am using a Script Editor webpart not a Content Web Part

(*********
 var x=document.getElementsByTagName(“input”);
 for (var i=0; i ******************)

Comment: I haven't look into Why your code does not work. A note on your DOM selection: No need to loop over **all** inputs when you use ``document.querySelectorAll("input[value='Save and Close']");``, and then loop over (only the Save and Close buttons) with: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/loop-queryselectorall-matches/